# Sales and multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Stack Overflow community! I have a query that is showing multiple results for the product name, and i'm trying to have the results show up as one. Basically, I'm trying to create a report that displays the product unit sales, and the end result should show each product once, and the total units sold for the product. Any advice is truly helpful, thank you!

```
select count(distinct p.ProductID), p.ProductName, od.Quantity,
p.UnitPrice
from Products p
full join OrderDetails od
on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by p.ProductName, od.Quantity, p.UnitPrice
```

Comment: Any table Schema of Product and OrderDetails, Sample Input and Expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice, SUM(od.Quantity) AS total_sold
from Products p
join OrderDetails od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by p.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
select p.ProductName, sum(od.Quantity)
from Products p left join
     OrderDetails od
     on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by p.ProductName;
```

Notes:

- Don't include columns in the `select` that you don't need.
- `full outer join` is almost never necessary.  A `left join` will return all products, even those with no orders.  An `inner join` is probably sufficient.
- Aggregate by the column(s) that uniquely define each row.